# How can i change color of mat-icon in mat-table based on value in cell

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i specify the color of an mat-icon in mat-table ? I have a color called dflt which is either true or false and i want to display either a green check or a red close. In my code currently i use

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="dflt">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Default </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <mat-icon>{{element.dflt ? 'check' : 'close'}}</mat-icon>{{element.dflt}} </td>
          </ng-container>
```

since if i want to for example change to red i would have to use **color="warn"**. So how can i specify a different image based on the value as well as a different color ? I tried something like this but that does not work.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dflt ? '<mat-icon color="warn">check</mat-icon>' : '<mat-icon color="primary">close</mat-icon>'}} </td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use *ngIf in the cell:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="dflt">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Default </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    <mat-icon *ngIf="element.dflt" color="warn">check</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!element.dflt" color="primary">close</mat-icon>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-cell-icon-color?embed=1&file=app/table-example.html

Comment: That’s what I came up my self as I could not find another way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You just had to put a class into your `mat-icon` like this :

```html
<mat-icon [color]="element.dlft ? 'warn' : 'green'">...</mat-icon>
```

Comment: That only allows me to specify one class , I need a way to change color based on icon

Comment: @MisterniceGuy I updated my code. That's what you need ?